# SOAP response deserialization not working with local client object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, httpclient, xml-serialization

I'm experiencing an error while trying to deserialization a SOAP response. I am able t o retrieve the response as a string, I took the string and generated the c# class from the xml, however, when I call

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var httpContent = new StringContent(xmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", Common.EPhytoNamespace);

            HttpResponseMessage message = httpClient.PostAsync(_settings.HubServiceUrl, httpContent).Result;
            envelope = message.Content.ReadAsAsync<HubServiceContracts.TrackingInfo.Envelope>().Result;
        }
```

I get the following exception:

> SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 65. Expecting element 'Envelope' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eCert.Bll.HubServiceContracts.TrackingInfo'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Envelope', namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'.

This is the structure of the generated c# objects:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GetEnvelopeTrackingInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://ephyto.ippc.int/")]
    public GetEnvelopeTrackingInfoResponse GetEnvelopeTrackingInfoResponse { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "S", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```

Please may you assist to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It doesn't look like that the type `HubServiceContracts.TrackingInfo.Envelope` is actually the Envelope class you show the code for.

Comment: hi Rene, the response from the service does not include my local namespace, however, for some reason it is expecting my local namespace to be included in the response.

Comment: No, it is not expecting your localnamespace in the response. It does get a soap envelope but your type isn't accepting that. Are you  100% sure that in this line `envelope = message.Content.ReadAsAsync<HubServiceContracts.TrackingInfo.Envelope>().Result;` that type `HubServiceContracts.TrackingInfo.Envelope` is the same type as the `public class Envelope` that you show in your question?

Comment: Get the schema from : http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eCert.Bll.HubServiceContracts.TrackingInfo.  It is missing envelope.